# Testing a React buttons CSS hover rule

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I need to test that an outline is visible on a button and I want to do it a unit test level. I have the following:

1. React
2. React testing library
3. Jest
4. Styled components

The code looks like
[image]

I have tried everything I can possibly think of. I can assert `focus` , I know it has focused on the right button, but I cannot assert the focus styling. I have tried focus event listeners, computedStyle etc etc. How can this be done at a unit level? TIA

Answer (score 0):

From [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle) github, I think the assertion is `toHaveStyle` without the word `Rule`. If that doesn't work for you either, you can try asserting the button has the class that gives it its focused state with `toHaveClass()`

Also, these are the examples they provide on how to use that assertion and I think you are not using it correctly:

```
const button = getByTestId('delete-button')>

expect(button).toHaveStyle('display: none')
expect(button).toHaveStyle({display: 'none'})
expect(button).toHaveStyle(`
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
`)

expect(button).toHaveStyle({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    display: 'none',
})
expect(button).not.toHaveStyle(`
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
`)

expect(button).not.toHaveStyle({
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    display: 'none',
})
```